# How to enable adb after wiping system and installing new kernel?

Tags: android, adb, nexus-4

I have a Nexus 4. I accidently wiped system and tried to restore it unsuccessfully. 
I did have adb before I wiped the system. Now I can only get into recovery mode. When I use Nexus root toolkit it recognizes the device only in bootloader but it can't recognize it as adb device. I thought maybe now that Android is not installed USB, debugging is disabled as default.
Do I have a way to enable it or do you have any other solution? I can't use the device. Do I have any other way to install Android without adb?

Comment: By the way, this question will be moved to the superuser stack exchange site. http://superuser.com/ This really wasn't a programming question, just an advanced user question.

Answer (score 0):

adb isn't required (adb is only one of the ways to do it. As long as you still have access to recovery mode, you're golden).

Just get the zipped image you want to install (a modded one, or the official one). You should be able to get the official one from google since it's a Nexus 4. Do not unzip it.

Connect your phone to your computer as a usb drive. Copy the zip file to the root of your internal sdcard on your phone.

Reboot your phone into recovery mode. Then navigate the menu on the phone with the sound rocker and the power key to tell it where to find the new location of the new image.

Then reboot normally. I'm writing this from memory. If you want more specific instructions, I can provide them if you want.

Comment: If you can send instructions that will be great but I am not sure about recovery mode. I do get the android image but it seems I can't do anything when I select recovery mode it just turns off

Comment: If one of the volume keys doesn't work during recovery mode, then you're out of luck. That would mean that recovery mode couldn't even boot properly. Can you double-check that part again? By the way, who did you buy your Nexus 4 from?

Comment: Well I checked it over and over but nothing. I bought it from google store but it have no warranty anymore because I Unlocked it

Comment: Solved it! That was very simple. In "Nexus root Toolkit" there is an option "Flash Stock + Unroot" you have to check radio button "Soft-Bricked/Bootloop" and this will do full factory reset from factory imageafter unrooting. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it! By the way, I know companies are not obligated to honor your warranty once you root your device, but for me, Sprint fixed my phone for free even thought it was rooted and obviously had another rom on it (but then again, the amount of money I was already spending with Sprint every month made it a cost-effective decision for them).